# What method could I use to monitor web page/frame changes and click new result?

Tags: java, iframe

My goal is to refresh and monitor a Web page in intervals, as well as click any new links that are present. Sort of like the opposite of a bid sniping bot?

I have brief experience with imacros, can this be used? I can do the refresh no issue but the specific element click is what I'm clueless on.

I apologize if this has an answer already. I'm sure it does,  this is SO.If you could lead me to the right material, I'd greatly appreciate it.

I tried searching but wasn't even sure what to look for.  I found something about ajax, but not sure if this is helpful to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to take a look at [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/).
It lets you do quite extensive automation of browsers. Unless i did not understand your question correctly, it should offer you the functionality you are looking for.

Comment: I've looked into Selenium and now have Selenium IDE and FlowControl, but I'm stuck on a couple of things.

 I decided to try and open the url, store the text of the element, refresh the page and check the text of the same element to see if it has changed or not. If it has I want to click the static link next to the text (in the next cell over). If the text hasn't changed, I want to loop until it has.

Comment: @Nala you may want to create a new question for that, so other people notice it, too. I am not a very experienced Selenium user, sorry!

Comment: No worries, I appreciate your help! Definitely pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: Glad i could help at least a bit :-)

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to catch data,right?
Ok this is a bit difficult because you want to collect some data and then you want to see the result.
First of all let's create a function to collect data:

```
  var x=0; //let's see how many clicks...
  var y=[]; //let's see what is clicked
  function collect(id){ //id is an argument...
  x++;//let's increase our variable counter...
  y.push(document.getElementById(id).href); //href is the link of the a element,the link in poor words...
  }
  function Show(){//let's show the result
  alert(y.toString());//This is the result of the data collect by the array y
  }
```

Ok let's put this in a small example

```
 <html>
 <body>
 <a href="http://www.github.com" onClick="collect();show();">1 link</a>
 <a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com" onClick="collect();show();">2 link</a>
 <a href="http://www.google.com" onClick="collect();show();">3 link</a>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Is this your idea?